# Compiling OpenGL ES C code using gcc and Cygwin

Tags: gcc, opengl-es, cygwin

I've installed Cygwin with gcc, opengl, glut.

I can compile and run simple OpenGL/GLUT sample code (e.g. NeHe lessons), however I need to compile and run OpenGL ES (1.1) code (to use, for example glOrthof).

Attempts obviously fail as the opengl packages I've installed via Cygwin don't provide OpenGL ES functionality.

Can I do this with my existing setup, or do I need to use MinGW?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Why can't you use `glOrtho` instead of `glOrthof`?

Comment: I'm attempting to cross-compile an iPhone/Android game written in C which uses ES (just the C portion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Recent Mesa3D documentation](http://www.mesa3d.org/opengles.html) suggests it might work.

There's also [Vincent](http://www.vincent3d.com/software/ogles1/ogles1.html).